# Israeli Chazzan outside of Israel says "tal umotor" at the right time for him but not us

Tags: halacha, mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader, chutz-laaretz, geshem-tal-ruach

We know that the shaliach tzibbur must follow the local custom even to the extent of [his own silent Amidah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=206) .

What should be done, then, when a resident of Israel who is acting as shaliach tzibbur outside of Israel between 7 Cheshvan and 4/5 December, already said “vetain tal umotor”in the repetition of the amidah?

It seems to me that he must correct the mistake; is that right?

Comment: The question can be asked the other way too.

Comment: The question can also be asked about someone not the _shatz_: I would think that maybe he prays like his surroundings, since praying for rain when it's not needed is (IIRC) tantamount to praying for something bad (why saying _v'sen tal umatar_ in the summer is worse than skipping it in winter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the article here: http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1777

My short summary is that most poskim hold he should not be chazzan even if he is an avel. R Shlomo Zalman Aurbach holds that he may be chazzan if necessary and should recite according to the local custom. We see everyone holds he should not change from the community.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2787#3a