# V'Sain Tal U'Matar for someone from Eretz Yisrael in Chutz L'Aretz (and vice versa)

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, eretz-yisrael, travel, chutz-laaretz, geshem-tal-ruach

In Eretz Yisrael we start saying V'Sain Tal U'Matar on the 7th of Cheshvan. If someone from Eretz Yisrael will be in America on the 7th of Cheshvan and will be flying back to Eretz Yisrael a few days after that what is the halacha in regards to when they should start saying V'Sain Tal U'Matar?

So too in the opposite case: when someone from America is in Eretz Yisrael on the 7th of Cheshvan but will be returning to America afterwards (before they begin to say there.) What is the halacha by this person?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12014/759

Comment: http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1777 http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2787#3a

Comment: When a friend of mine visited Israel in mid-November, he was told to start saying v'tain tal u'matar when he got there and then to continue saying it until Pesach.  Using this logic, an Israeli in the chu"l would delay saying it until they got home.

Answer (score 1):

See mishnah berurah hilchos tefilla in simon dealing with saying tal u-motor
Mishnah berurah first says that you should keep saying what they were saying at your point of origin

Then he brings down a differing opinion that you should follow what they are saying at your destination ( but he also says that this may be dependent on how long you are spending at your destination; and that only if you are staying at least a year, you should follow what they are saying at your destination town )

Comment: There was a link given in the comments to an answer that discusses and brings all the relevant teshuvas and sources on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yisroel Silberstein, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. [Editing into your answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/22252/edit) an exact reference (_siman_ and _s'if katan_) to the _MB_ would improve your answer, as would [noting in the answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/22252/edit) whether the _MB_ was discussing the same case mentioned in the question or a similar one. Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.